# How to get a predicted image of YOLOv5 model?

Tags: opencv, pytorch, yolo

I'm trying to load YOLOv5 model and using it to predict specific image. My problem is I want to show predicted image with bounding box into my application so I need to get it directly from the predict method of PyTorch to show in my application.

```
    model = torch.hub.load('yolov5', 'custom', path=model_name, force_reload=True, 
    source='local')
    pred = model(image)
    pred.show() #show image but can't assign to a variable
    pred.save() #save image to runs\detect\exp
```

I want something like:

```
    predict_image = model(image)
    cv2.imshow('Predict', predict_image)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `pred = model(image)` -- this does not predict an image, but a list of box candidates. you have to filter those by prob, apply nms, then you can *draw your own image*

Comment: you might need to do something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272086/after-finetuning-faster-rcnn-object-detection-model-how-to-visualize-bbox-predi?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick workaround will be to use "imgs" object from "pred" like the following:

```
predict_image = model(image)
im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(predict_image.imgs[0], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Because of OpenCV reading images as BGR
cv2_imshow(im_rgb)
```

I wish this will help you, have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I tried to use this, it's only return the original image without bounding box.

Comment: It means there is no detections in the image. You are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Because the Answer from @mak13 did not work for me and i wanted to understand this behaviour, here is my solution:

### Simple get the image as variable

```py
import torch
import pathlib

img_path = pathlib.Path("test_img.jpg")

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5n')
results = model(img_path)
r_img = results.render() # returns a list with the images as np.array
img_with_boxes = r_img[0] # image with boxes as np.array
```

### Existing infos for this topic at GitHub

Looking into the official [Pytorch Hub Wiki from yolov5](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/36) in the section `Base64 Results` we find info on how to use `render` and also some handy info for yolov5 and REST API's and why this was implemented.

### Looking into the code to understand this behaviour

If take a look into the type of results `type(results)` we get `<class 'models.common.Detections'>` which we can find here at [yolov5's GitHub page](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/2373d5470e386a0c63c6ab77fbee6d699665e27b/utils/plots.py#L71).

This class has this (`render`, `show`, etc.) methods that run the `_run` method with different parameters. The `render` method will cause the `_run` method to override all images with the detected ones:

```py
if render:
    self.ims[i] = np.asarray(im)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer because it seems the resulting image data is not updated instantly and render() function enforces update.

Comment: ``cv2.imshow('Testing', r_img[0])`` delivers the right result for me. Thank you!